# Build of multiple entry point files in Dart have error as one has no init_autogenerated function defined

Tags: user-interface, web, build, dart

My app consists of two very similar entry point files, namely 'web/country_config.html', 'web/hotel_amenity_config.html'. Their HTML structure and logic are the same. The only difference lies in data. What's confusing is that the build does not work properly as 'web/country_config.html' has no init_autogenerated() function definition.

The build.dart looks like this:
  build(new Options().arguments, ['web/country_config.html', 'web/hotel_amenity_config.html']);

In the generated code 'web/out/country_config.html_bootstrap.dart', the statement of 'userMain.init_autogenerated();' has an warning: "The function 'init_autogenerated' is not defined". During runtime, the page won't show up properly.

When I looked into 'web/out/country_config.dart' and found that it really has no init_autogenerated() function.

At the beginning, I thought the similarity between the two files may be the reason. Later, I found that it happened even when the entry point files are totally different. For entry point files, I mean the two html files link to distinct Dart files, each of which has main() function. Hence, both of them are entry points.

My current workaround is to build entry point files one by one and recheck if any of the generated dart files miss init_autogenerated() function. It's time-consuming, however. I wonder if I could build multiple entry point files simultaneously in a reliable way?

Comment: Jihong, I'm not totally sure I understand the question. Do web/country_config.html and web/hotel_amenity_config.html' link to distinct Dart files or to the same Dart file? And are you running the files from inside the out/ directory?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question so that it is clearer.

Comment: Are you using [web-ui](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui)? That's the only thing that came up when I googled for `init_autogenerated` because otherwise it's not a standard function AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, both the two html files use web-ui. From the generated code in the init_autogenerated(), I can see its main function is to setup data binding, event listening and component instantiation.